# How to set range of Dates in Calendar View in Android

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

The documentation of `Calendar` View says

> range of dates is configurable

Can anyone help me to understand this line. Also does it mean `Calendar` View supports date range selection?

Following is the link of article I'm referring to:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixil5.png

I want to select a range of dates using `calendar` view. However i have searched everything but cannot seem to find the solution to select range of date using `Calendar` View.